# getting rid of blank information

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm still new to Crystal Reports so I'm not sure how to ask this question, but I'll try:  my report is set by job #'s I added a table for serive operations.  I only want the description of these services to print on my report (some of these services have descriptions some do not). Right now if there are 4 blank lines and 1 with data, the job is coming out 5 times (4 times with blank space and 1 with the info. I want.  How do I get it to print only the ones with descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

record selection formula:

Not(IsNull({ServicesTable.Description}))

Answer (score 0):

Add a restriction to your record selection formula that says something like

```
Len({ServicesTable.Description}) <> 0
```